# Copy conditional formula to cells in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have figures in various cells in columns D & F.

In column G2 is the formula = G1-D2+F2, this formula is repeated with the relative references down column G.

My problem is I want to hide the formula in column G if both the relative cells in D & F are empty. I have used conditioning formatting to hide the formula in one cell but when I try to copy the formatting to other cells it retains the absolute address of the cells in D & F, that is it does not adjust the condition to the relative cells.

Any suggestions or the vba code to overcome this problem would be great.

Comment: Why is this VBA? You should just need to check if there is a value in at least one of D2/F2 before showing the result of the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the formula to show a value when at least one of D2:F2 contains a value values.

```
=IF(AND($D2<>"", $F2<>""), "", $G1-$D2+$F2)
```

Comment: this formula will give me any empty cell but I need the cell to have the correct value but be hidden for example, if G1 = 10,000 and both D2 & F2 are empty, then G2 should have a value of 10,000 but it would be hidden.

Comment: Use a Conditional Formatting Rule based on the formula `=AND($D2<>"", $F2<>"")` and set the Number format to custom with a Type: of `;;;` (three semi-colons).

Comment: Thanks Jeeped, Your conditional formula worked fine. Thanks for your assistance